# MySQL How to use REGEXP to Filter one column's rows by another column's rows

Tags: mysql, regex

1. One table t1 has a `partnercode` column that (SELECT partnercode from t1) returns 1859 varchar rows.
2. On another table t2 with a `username` varchar column (with no key relationship to t1), I need to write a query that removes all rows where t2.username starts with any of the string values from t1.partnercode.

I attempted to do this with the query:

```
SELECT t2.username FROM t2 where t2.username NOT REGEXP(CONCAT_WS("|^", SELECT partnercode from t1))
```

and got Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row.

I know if I supply the individual strings to the REGEXP() function and prepend them with ^, that will remove the correct values. But in an instance where I have 1859 rows of those values, I am not sure of the correct way to proceed.

Records from t1.partnercode
1031
1032
121CM
1234

Records from t2.username
1031-PNGUQG
1032-X2NOAN121
121CM-VBFWAA13b
1234-SETJ6b5

In the sample data above all records from t2.username should be filtered out of the query.

Comment: Its strange database schema...

Comment: They are from different databases. One was used to populate the other in a legacy system that the company no longer uses.

Comment: Paste a few records from each table. People can help you more effectively if they can see some representative data. Be sure to indicate which records are `t1` and which are `t2`.

Comment: This is so inefficient. Seriously consider normalising your schema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about

```
  SELECT t2.username 
    FROM t2 
    where not exists (select null 
                        from t1 
                        where t2.username REGEXP CONCAT("^", t1.partnercode)
```

Using exists makes the condition only consider one row at a time.

Comment: Bingo! That did it. I'll be making a note about the not exists/exists forcing the condition to consider one row at a time. Thanks for your help!